# How to get an integer dynamically from another class?

Tags: c++

I'm working on pacman game with Qt. I got two classes, **Ghost** and **Pacman**, both inherited from an abstract class **MovableItem** (which is compulsory, since we are required to apply polymorphism).

In the ghosts' moving algorithm, I need the location of pacman, which are data members `pacX` and `pacY` in **Pacman**, trying to make the ghost chase the pacman by comparing their positions.

I've tried to create a pacman object in **Ghost**, and also tried to use get function to get `pacX` and `pacY`. But the position of pacman I get in **Ghost** is always its starting position. Is there any way that I can get new value of the two data members in **Ghost** when the game is running?

---

Sorry for not being specific. When the game starts, function `starttt` is called, and all the ghosts and pacman are created:

```
void MainWindow::starttt()
{
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    ghostTimer = new QTimer(this);
    map = new PacmanMap;
    pacman = new Pacman;
    ghost1 = new Ghost;
    ghost2 = new Ghost;
    ghost3 = new Ghost;
    ghost4 = new Ghost;
    scene->addItem(map);
    scene->addItem(pacman);
    scene->addItem(ghost1);
    scene->addItem(ghost2);
    scene->addItem(ghost3);
    scene->addItem(ghost4);
```

And the direction of pacman is set by WASD keys and pass to **Pacman**:

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
        switch (event->key())
        {
        case Qt::Key_W:
            if(!pacman->getMoving())
                pacman->setDirection(1);
            else
                pacman->setNextDirection(1);
            break;
```

In **Pacman**, the starting position of pacman is declared in constructor, and changed in this way:

```
void Pacman::move(int)
{
    QPoint p;
    switch(direction)
    {
    case 1:
        p.setX(pacX);
        p.setY(pacY-5);
        setDirection(direction);

        if(mapmap->canMove(p))
        {
            pacY-=5;
            moving = true;
        }
        else {
            moving = false;
        }
        break;
        ...
        ...

    setPacX(pacX);
    setPacY(pacY);
}
}
```

In **Ghost**, I create a new Pacman in constructor, and I want the ghost to chase the pacman by getting its current position:

```
void Ghost::ghostMove2()
{
    if(!moving)
    {
        if(direction==1||direction==2)
        {
            if(ghostX > pacman->pacX)
                direction = 3;
            else if(ghostX < pacman->pacX)
                direction = 4;
            else if(ghostX == pacman->pacX)
            {
                if(ghostY > pacman->pacY)
                    direction = 1;
                else if(ghostY < pacman->pacY)
                    direction = 2;
            }
        }
        else if(direction==3 || direction==4)
        {
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: You need to give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which will let people replicate your error and know if they've found the actual fix.

Comment: Unrelated: *`pacX` and `pacY` in **Pacman***, not just plain old `X` and `Y` in `MovableItem`? Seems like a more logical place to store the position of a `MovableItem`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating a new Pacman each time you try to get the position, it'll always be at the starting position. In addition, if your `Ghost` class stores a different Pacman than the Pacman you're moving around and displaying on-screen, it'll (also) always be at the starting position.

When you create `Ghost` ensure that it's pointing to the *right* Pacman object:

```
int main() {
    Pacman pacman = ...; 
    Ghost ghost = ...;
    ghost.setPacman(&pacman); 
}
```